# iBeaconでエリア毎に動作を分ける方法

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

iBeaconを複数個設置し、それぞれのBeaconのエリア内に入った際に別の動作(バックグラウンド)をさせるようにしたいと考えています。

同一UUIDでMajorを変えることでできるかと思いましたが、didEnterRegion内ではどのMajorのBeaconを掴んでエリア内に入ったかを認識することは可能でしょうか？

もしくは複数個のUUIDのビーコンをモニタリングし、それぞれのUUID毎のエリアに入った際の動作を決めることになるのでしょうか？

Comment: ibeaconのタグを追加しました。

Answer (score 3):

didEnterRegionではMajor,Minorは取得出来なかったと思います。

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
    if ([region isMemberOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]){
        [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region];
    }
}
```

上記の様にdidEnterRegion内でstartRangingBeaconsInRegionを呼び出し、

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{
    for(CLBeacon *beacon in beacons){
        if([beacon.major intValue] == 1){
            //処理
        }
    }
}
```

didRangeBeacons内で判別が出来るはずです。

Answer (score 2):

直接iBeaconのコードを組んだことはないので申し訳ないですが、GeoFencingで同じようなことをしていました。以下のような感じでmajorが参照できるのではないでしょうか？

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
         didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {
        CLBeaconRegion *bregion = (CLBeaconRegion *)region;
        if ([bregion.major intValue] == 1) {
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

didEnterRegion内では、major, minorなどのBeaconの詳細情報を取得することはできません。
major, minor情報はdidRangeBeacons内でのみ取得が可能です。

しかし、didRangeBeaconsはバックグラウンドで実行し続けることができません。
バックグランドで利用するのであれば、
didEnterRegionをトリガーにstartRangingBeaconsInRegionを実行して、
約10秒程度の間だけ取得可能なmajor, minorの値で処理をすれば良いのではないでしょうか？

ただし、Beaconの機器が近かったり、電波出力が大きかったりする場合は、
同じUUIDだと領域が重複するため、注意が必要です。
その場合はUUIDを別にした方が良いかもしれません。